# No bootable medium found! System halted. になる

Tags: virtualbox

**状況**

1. VirtualBoxにWindows10(64bit)の仮想マシンを作成。
2. Win10_1803_Japanese_X64.isoを選択
3. 仮想マシン起動

**エラー内容**

```
FATAL:No bootable medium found! System halted.
```

仮想マシンに Win10_1803_Japanese_X64.iso のOSが入ってない状況なのでしょうか。
VirtualBoxに不慣れなので、原因特定に時間がかかってます。
お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

追記
システムで起動順序が変更できません。
この半透明状態で起動順序を変更する術を知っている方がいればご教示ください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**環境**

macOS HighSierra macOS HighSierra 10.13.6
VirtualBox バージョン 5.2.12

Comment: isoはどこに用意していますか？CDですか？

Comment: Finderの中のダウンロードの中にiosファイルを置いてます。

Comment: CD/DVD経由なしでOSにisoファイルって入れれるんですよね？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

考え方としては物理マシンにOSをインストールする時と同じで、インストールメディア(CD/DVD等)をHDDよりも先に参照するよう設定する必要があります。

- 仮想マシンの設定でインストールに使用するISOイメージが「ストレージ」で選択されているか確認。
- 同じく仮想マシンの設定で「システム」>「マザーボード」の「起動順序」で**光学**をハードディスクより上に移動しておく。

もしくは

- 仮想マシン(ゲストOS)を起動してVirtualBoxのロゴが出ている画面で<kbd>F12</kbd>を何度か押すと(一時的な)ブートデバイスの選択画面が出るので、**CD-ROM**を選択。

Comment: 仮想マシンの設定でインストールに使用するISOイメージが「ストレージ」で選択されているか確認。選択されている。

Comment: 同じく仮想マシンの設定で「システム」>「マザーボード」の「起動順序」で光学をハードディスクより上に移動しておく。起動順序がフロッピー,光学,ハードディスクなので順番を変更したいのですが、変更できないようになってます。(文字が半透明でクリックしても反応しない)

Comment: ↑の状況で、システムで順番を変更する方法はご存知ないでしょうか。

Comment: @blockchain2018 もしかして、仮想マシン起動状態で変更しようとしていませんか？

Comment: 仮想マシンの起動中は(一部を除いて)オプションを変更することはできません。変更するならいったんシャットダウンしておく必要があります。

Comment: @Myaku  起動ではなく、保存状態ですが変更できません。

Comment: @cubick 電源オフ状態にしたら変更できるようになりました

Comment: ありがとうございます。Windowsのセットアップ画面まで辿りつけました

Answer (score -1):

Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.2-119230.vbox-extpack