# VirtualBoxでゲストOSのインストールできないFATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted

Tags: virtualbox

## 状況

1. VirtualBoxにWindows10(64bit)の仮想マシンを作成。
2. Win10home64.isoを選択
3. 仮想マシン起動

## エラー内容

```
FATAL:No bootable medium found! System halted.
```

## 環境

- Windows10 Home 64bit バージョン 1809
- VirtualBox バージョン 6.0.8 r130520 (Qt5.6.2)

## 実行手順

1. BIOSでSVM > [Enabled]を確認
2. ISOファイルをC:に移動
3. VirtualBoxの起動順でCDROMを優先に設定
4. 起動ハードディスクを選択時にISOを設定
5. 起動ハードディスクを選択時に物理CDROMドライブを設定
6. 仮想マシンの設定でインストールに使用するISOイメージをストレージで選択
7. 仮想マシン(ゲストOS)を起動してVirtualBoxのロゴが出ている画面でF12を何度か押すと(一時的な)ブートデバイスの選択画面が出るので、CD-ROMを選択
8. 起動ウィンドウの「デバイス」→「CD/DVDデバイス」→「仮想CD/DVDディスクファイルの選択」から、起動したいOSの「.iso」ファイルを選択し、再起動。

以上を試してみましたが状況に変化ありません。
自分でも色々調べてますが未だに原因が特定できずにおります。
お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願いします。

## 追記

ストレージを２つ設定した状態の画像を添付します。

[image: ストレージを２つ設定した状態の画像を添付します。]

Comment: こちらの質問と同じ現象のようですがご覧になられましたか？ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48584/

Comment: はい。エラーメッセージで検索したところそちらの質問に辿り着いたので試してみたのですが解決できなかったため同じような題名で投稿しました。起動順は変更可能な状態です。

Comment: わかりにくくて申し訳ありません。手順４～６についてはそれぞれ新規に作成して１つずつ試しております。光学ドライブのみを１つ設定して起動、仮想マシンを除去後に新規作成してISOファイルのみを１つ設定して起動といった状態です。物理ディスク・ISOファイル両方あります。8については他サイトで見つけた情報で物理ディスクで起動後エラー状態からISOファイルを設定してみました。今物理ディスクとISOファイルを両方設定されている状態です。

Comment: No bootable medium found!と表示されるんなら、使用している.isoファイルがブート可能に作られていないのではないですか?ブート可能であることはなんらかの方法で確かめられましたでしょうか?

Comment: ブート可能かどうかについて確認方法がよくわかりません。ＩＳＯファイルをエクスプローラからダブルクリックでセットアップは実行されましたが、物理ディスクをＤＡＥＭＯＮＴＯＯＬＳでＩＳＯファイルにしただけのものはブート不可能なのでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。評価版ソフトウェアのISOファイルを使用したところ問題なくインストール開始しました。物理ディスクが破損していたためディスク及びISOファイルどちらもインストール失敗していた模様です。お二人ともお手数をお掛け致しました。お騒がせ致しました。

Comment: @kawa 回答として纏めました。

Answer (score 1):

まずはISOファイルが設定からマウントされていることを確認する必要があります。
既存の質問がありますのでご確認ください。
[No bootable medium found! System halted.になる。(virtual box)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/48584/)
[image: ストレージデバイス]

ほか、既存の質問の手順を行っても問題が発生する場合、
ブート可能なディスクではないか、破損している可能性があります。

ここでいうブート可能とは、"起動ディスクであり、OSに依存せず動作する"ことです。
ディスクイメージを物理ディスクに焼き起こすなどして、
ホストコンピュータ、物理マシン側でディスクを挿入して、ブートするか確かめてください。

また、手順が正しいか、ISOファイルが破損しているか分からない場合、
[Windows評価版ソフトウェア](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise)というものがあるので、
一度こちらのISOファイルを使ってインストール手順を確認してみてください。
もしこちらのISOファイルでインストールが出来た場合、ファイルに問題がある可能性があります。